# Django Haystack: Range search on MultiValueField

Tags: django, django-haystack

I was wondering if it is possible to do a range search on a MultiValueField. I have a model that looks like the following:

```
Book
   Title = 'Awesome Book'
   Prices = [ Decimal('10.00'), Decimal('15.00'), Decimal('20.00') ]
```

I am indexing the prices field with a MultiValueField and I would like to be able to do the follow:

```
sqs = SearchQueryResult()
sqs.filter(prices__gt=Decimal('10.00'), prices__lt=Decimal('20.00'))
```

Is this possible or do I have to use something else to do a range search on multiple values?

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that the __gt doesn't work and I think it's because it's indexing it as a list of strings. I found the following [link](http://groups.google.com/group/django-haystack/browse_thread/thread/9bc25e66e2ed1bad/0b3cf2b5b9430e6e?lnk=gst&q=strongly+typed#0b3cf2b5b9430e6e) where they talk about subclassing MultiValueField. I tried this but I can't get it to give me a list of decimals. The subclassed MultiValueFiled looks like the following:

```
class MultiValueDecimalField(fields.MultiValueField):
    field_type = 'decimal'
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this problem is doing the following:

```
sqs.filter(prices__in=['%.2f' % (x/100.00) for x in range(1000, 2000)])
```

It's very ugly but it works. Still open to other answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing: when I applied filters __gte, __gt etc. I noticed that SearchQuerySet returns incorrect data. When I changed field type to FloatField everything started working right. looks like bug, or smth

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the range field lookup?

`SearchQuerySet().filter(view_count__range=[3, 5])`

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#field-lookups